# parent child sql tables to nested json data

Tags: mysql, sql, json, adjacency-list

I have 2 SQL tables , table Parent, and child….

I want to make a subquery or union or join (it is no difference) to show this parent child table ( in my case with nodeJs ) in nested json data like this

Parent Table :

```
ParentId    ParentName        ParentDescription 
---------------------------------------------------------
1        |  ParentName1   |   ParentDescription1 
2        |  ParentName2   |   ParentDescription2 
3        |  ParentName3   |   ParentDescription3 
4        |  ParentName4   |   ParentDescription4
```

Child Table:

```
childId        childName          childDescription     ParentId(foreign key)
---------------------------------------------------------
1        |     childName1      |   childDescription1      1
2        |     childName2      |   childDescription2      1
3        |     childName3      |   childDescription3      1
4        |     childName4      |   childDescription4      1
5        |     childName5      |   childDescription5      2
6        |     childName6      |   childDescription6      2
7        |     childName7      |   childDescription7      2
8        |     childName8      |   childDescription8      2
```

and I want to show the json nested data  like this … ,,I know how to implement this data with json stringfy in backend ,,, .. **my question** is that how to make a subquery or recursive sql query to do this

```
[
  {
    "parentId": 1,
    "parentName": " ParentName1 ",
    "ParentDescription": "ParentDescription1 " , 
       [
        { "childId": 1,
          "childName": "childName1",
          "childDescription": "childDescription1",
        },
          { "childId": 2,
          "childName": "childName2",
          "childDescription": "childDescription2",
        },
          { "childId": 3,
          "childName": "childName3",
          "childDescription": "childDescription3",
        },
           { "childId": 4,
          "childName": "childName3",
          "childDescription": "childDescription3",
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "parentId": 2,
    "parentName": " ParentName2 ",
    "ParentDescription": "ParentDescription2 " , 
       [
        { "childId": 5,
          "childName": "childName5",
          "childDescription": "childDescription1",
        },
          { "childId": 6,
          "childName": "childName6",
          "childDescription": "childDescription2",
        },
          { "childId": 7,
          "childName": "childName7",
          "childDescription": "childDescription3",
        },
           { "childId": 8,
          "childName": "childName8",
          "childDescription": "childDescription3",
        }
      ]
  },

…
…
…
…
…
...
]
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the brand of RDBMS you're using, for instance [tag:sql-server], [tag:mysql], [tag:postgresql]... Different brands have different JSON features, so you need to be specific to get the best answer.

Comment: The `rdbms` tag is irrelevant to this question. To answer the question, one must know what database brand you are working with - because every brand has it's own json support features - A solution for SQL Server will probably not work with MySql, and a solution for Oracle will probably not work with postgreSql.